# Using greater than with Lo Dash

Tags: reactjs, filter, lodash

How do I filter an array using greater and less than with Lo Dash?

Using Lo Dash's _.find [demo data](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#find):

```
 var users = [
  { 'user': 'barney',  'age': 36, 'active': true },
  { 'user': 'fred',    'age': 40, 'active': false },
  { 'user': 'pebbles', 'age': 1,  'active': true }
];
```

I would like to find all users over 30.

`var over30 = _.find(users, function(o) { return o.age > 30; });`

However this returns the first user, Barney, instead of Barney and Fred.

I've tried different combinations of the following.

```
_.find(users, ['age', > 30]);
```

Comment: It's worth noting this can be accomplished with native functions as well: `[{age: 36}, {age: 40}, {age: 1}].filter(p => p.age > 30)`;

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `filter()` method instead. `filter`  will return all elements that pass the condition while `find` will exit the loop and return the first element that returns true on condition.

```js
var users = [
  { 'user': 'barney',  'age': 36, 'active': true },
  { 'user': 'fred',    'age': 40, 'active': false },
  { 'user': 'pebbles', 'age': 1,  'active': true }
];

var over30 = _.filter(users, ({age}) => age > 30)
console.log(over30)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Worked beautifully! Thank you Nenad :)

Answer (score 1):

From the [DOC](https://lodash.com/docs/#find):

> find, Iterates over elements of collection, returning the first
>   element predicate returns truthy for.

`find` always returns the first element not all the element who satisfy the condition.

You need to use [filter](https://lodash.com/docs/#filter):

> Iterates over elements of collection, returning an array of all
>   elements predicate returns truthy for.

Write it like this:

```
var over30 = _.filter(users, function(o) { return o.age > 30; })
```

Working snippet:

```js
var users = [
  { 'user': 'barney',  'age': 36, 'active': true },
  { 'user': 'fred',    'age': 40, 'active': false },
  { 'user': 'pebbles', 'age': 1,  'active': true }
];

var over30 = _.filter(users, el => el.age > 30);

console.log('over30 = ', over30);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for the clarification Mayank

Comment: glad, it helped you :)